# Wrapping a word with html using Javascript's replace() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm trying to use Javascript's built-in `replace()` method, but for some reason it won't allow me to wrap html around a word and output it to a textarea.

```
$(function() {
    $('#js-convert-markup').click(function() {
        var htmlToConvert = $('.markup_converter').val();
        htmlToConvert.replace('class', '<span class="admin_styles_type">class</span>');
        var convertedMarkup = $('.markup_converted').val(htmlToConvert);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/someprimetime/fmu5m/11/

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
htmlToConvert = htmlToConvert.replace('class', '<span class="admin_styles_type">class</span>');
```

Strings are immutable in JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/a26nf/

Answer (score 2):

replace returns a new string, it does not alter the original. You need to do:

```
htmlToConvert = htmlToConvert.replace(...)
```